# Get AWS REST API EC2 DescribeInstances as JSON response

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, api, rest, amazon-ec2

I've been digging into the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html) and could not find how to return JSON instead of XML when using the `DescribeInstances` endpoint. For example :

```bash
curl -H "Accept: application/json" https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances&Version=2016-11-15
```

returns :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>MissingParameter</Code><Message>The request must contain the parameter AWSAccessKeyId</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>b0d81b7f-35aa-42b9-a3bf-ff32aec40d8a</RequestID></Response>
```

While other endpoints work correctly. For example :

```bash
curl -H "Accept: application/json" https://kms.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListAliases&Version=2010-05-08
```

returns :

```json
{"Error":{"Code":"InvalidAction","Message":"Could not find operation ListAliases for version 2010-05-08","Type":"Sender"},"RequestId":"2bfe9f87-2e5b-4dfb-b09f-8f8db26a5054"}
```

Are the EC2 endpoints incompatible with JSON ? If so, how do they do it in the SDKs and clients ? They parse XML ?

Comment: I was looking for the same. They probably do not have EC2 endpoints returning JSON.There's also very hard to find which is the latest API version. is the 2016 the latest one?